Arch stuck at grub shell
After rebooting my laptop I am stuck at grub shell. Not sure what steps to recover.
I was going to arch-chroot my install from a live usb, but can't seem to do that with my setup:
Arch
BTRFS encrypted with LUKS (No LVM)
GRUB

I live booted into the live usb
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p2 arch
mount /dev/mapper/arch /mnt
arch-chroot /mnt

Output:
mount: /mnt/proc: mount point does not exist
dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
=> ERROR: failed to setup chroot /mnt

So I browsed /mnt and it lists subvolumes. However, I am not sure how to go about arch-chrooting into this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: poking around I changed directories to @/etc/ and cat out fstab
And fstab is empty.
All of my files are still there.

Someone else was able to help:
1 Open a terminal:
Unlock the LUKS partition:
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p2 arch

2 Mount the BTRFS filesystem:
Since BTRFS has subvolumes, you need to mount the correct subvolume:
mount -o subvol=@ /dev/mapper/arch /mnt

3 Mount the necessary virtual filesystems:
mount --types proc /proc /mnt/proc
mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --make-rslave /mnt/sys
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --make-rslave /mnt/dev

4 Bind the boot partition (if separate):
If you have a separate boot partition, you need to mount it too:
mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot

5 Chroot into your system:
arch-chroot /mnt

6 Fix your fstab:
Ensure that your /etc/fstab file inside the chroot environment is correctly set up. You might need to generate a new one using genfstab:
genfstab -U /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab

I copied one from a snapshot, so no need for me to regen fstab
7 Update GRUB:
Reinstall and update GRUB to ensure it is correctly installed:
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=GRUB
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Exit the chroot environment:
exit

Unmount all the filesystems:
bash

umount -R /mnt
cryptsetup luksClose arch

8 Reboot:
reboot


Mount the necessary virtual filesystems is unnecessary when you use arch-chroot, since it's a chroot wrapper that does that for you.
